# Visualize Tensorflow Graph from Checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I am importing a pretrained [mobilenet's model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) `mobilenet_v1_0.25_128_frozen.pb` into my tensorflow environment. Once imported, I want to be able to save a snapshot of the model architecture in the form of `.png`. I know that there is a way to do this in keras with `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="model.png")`. Is there a way to do this in tensorflow session without using Tensorboard. In case, you recommend using tensorboard, I don't want to separately run tensorboard. I want a way to save the model architecture inside the tensorflow session without starting tensorboard.

Comment: `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="model.png")` isn't related with tensorboard.

Comment: It is but you cannot use it inside tensorfloa session.

Comment: As you described your problem as "Is there a way to do this in tensorflow session without using Tensorboard.", `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` seems to satisfy your desire.